Mysql Database is not creating in workbench while installing the directus using docker compose yml file
I am trying to install the directus using docker-compose.yml file
I am using he below code.
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command:
        [
            "--character-set-server=utf8mb4",
            "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
            "--default-authentication-plugin=caching_sha2_password",
        ]
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'directus'
      MYSQL_USER: 'directus'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'directus'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
  directus:
    image: directus/directus:11.1.1
    ports:
      - 8055:8055
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:      
      KEY: 'da6d5a45d6ad65a4d65asd65as4d65a4sd65ad65a4d65'
      SECRET: '654d56asd6d65asd65asd56ad56ad56ad56ad4'
      ADMIN_EMAIL: 'admin@example.com'
      ADMIN_PASSWORD: 'd1r3ctu5'
      DB_CLIENT: 'mysql'
      DB_HOST: 'mysql'
      DB_PORT: '3306'
      DB_DATABASE: 'directus'
      DB_USER: 'root'
      DB_PASSWORD: 'root'
      WEBSOCKETS_ENABLED: "true"

While running the docker compose up command I am getting below error. and mysql database is not created
directus-1  | node:internal/process/promises:288
directus-1  | triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
directus-1  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:3306
directus-1  | at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16) {
directus-1  | errno: -111,
directus-1  | code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
directus-1  | syscall: 'connect',
directus-1  | address: '172.19.0.2',
directus-1  | port: 3306,
directus-1  | fatal: true
directus-1  | }
directus-1  |
directus-1  | Node.js v18.20.4
directus-1 exited with code 1

Also I am trying to connect in workbench but not db is there

How is any kind of workbench related to the problem?
